# Microphone Input

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get a microphone input event in c#?  I would like to display a progress bar that goes up and down with the voice level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This link may help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2009/10/08/9905168.aspx

The post includes instructions on capturing the microphone level, etc.

Comment: resource is no longer available.

Comment: The current version of this page is at [Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder).

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is example source code for a VU meter.  You can get the audio capture buffer with the Win32 API, but I've found it is far easier to use the BASS library.  There is a .NET wrapper for it that is used by many projects out in the wild.

BASS: http://www.un4seen.com/

BASS.NET:  http://www.un4seen.com/download.php?z/4/Bass24.Net.zip

In the examples zip file, you find some code for a VU meter.  Their DLL does all of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

XNA has support for capturing the microphone. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.microphone.aspx