# Monitor microphone changes

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, c++-cli

Is there any way to monitor microphone changes (plug in and plug out events)? Shouldn't matter if the mic is bluetooth / usb / or plugged directly to sound card.
Application is built with C# but if there isn't any good way to get the events using C# then C++/CLI might be also option.

Comment: If the microphone appears as a separate device (eg. shows in device manager) you can almost certainly use WMI events.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061741/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found also IMMNotificationClient from WASAPI which should work.
Seems NAudio is not exposing this, but after customization I'm able to use it and get plugin / plugout events. Although it doesn't seem really stable - duplicated events / missing events and etc. Is there any proper implementation example in managed level?

Interface description :: [IMMNotificationClient interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This link may help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2009/10/08/9905168.aspx

The post includes instructions on capturing the microphone level, etc.

Original post. [Microphone Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920049/microphone-input)

EDIT: Blog moved here: https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder